# How generate yii2 captcha and verifycode be unmber without any word?

Tags: security, yii2, captcha

I am trying to generate a captcha in yii2 with a verify code in number instead of string.
is there any way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extend `CaptchaAction` with your own class and override `generateVerifyCode()` there like:

```
<?php

namespace common\captcha;

use yii\captcha\CaptchaAction as DefaultCaptchaAction;

class CaptchaAction extends DefaultCaptchaAction
{
    protected function generateVerifyCode()
    {
        if ($this->minLength > $this->maxLength) {
            $this->maxLength = $this->minLength;
        }
        if ($this->minLength < 3) {
            $this->minLength = 3;
        }
        if ($this->maxLength > 8) {
            $this->maxLength = 8;
        }
        $length = mt_rand($this->minLength, $this->maxLength);
        $digits = '0123456789';
        $code = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
            $code .= $digits[mt_rand(0, 9)];
        }
        return $code;
    }
}
```

In this example class is saved in `common\captcha` folder. Remember to change the namespace if you would like to save it somewhere else.

Now you just need to use it in controller:

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'captcha' => [
            'class' => 'common\captcha\CaptchaAction', // change this as well in case of moving the class
        ],
    ];
}
```

The rest is exactly the same like with default captcha.

Comment: Thanks a lot. its work for me.
Now can you learn me how change defualt font for captcha?

Comment: There is attribute in CaptchaAction for that - `public $fontFile = '@yii/captcha/SpicyRice.ttf';` so you can override it as well in extended class.

Comment: Can I ask you, how can I output and validate captcha *without ActiveForm*? I mean, i don't using active form. But i want to output a captcha and check it. So i can to add in *actions()* method the *captcha* and then? xD

Comment: @Adobe You can use standard form generated with `yii\helpers\Html` class with standalone Captcha as widget (`Captcha::widget()`) - the rest is the same.